# select max from group-object

Tags: powershell-3.0

I wish to do the following on an array of files in powershell (expressed in pseudo-SQL)

```
select NAME, max(lastcreatedDate) from listOfFiles
group by NAME
```

I can use the `group-object` cmdlet to get the groups done, but how can I get the max bit?

**Note** Perhaps the `Measure-Object` cmdlet, but I can't seem to get it to deal with groups

Answer (score 5):

Given your comments below, I guess your file list comes from a recursive file search and in the end you want the FileInfo object of the newest file for each file name. Please update your question (including, in addition to what you already have there, at least the expected input (if my guess is correct it is a file list as given from `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File`) and requested output (again, my guess is that you want a FileInfo object for the newest file for each file name, without duplicates if older files would exist in other subfolders)) so that future readers will know if my guess was correct.

Given that I have understood your scenario correctly, I would probably Group by Name and then do a Foreach on the list of groups to just pick the newest file from each group. To test it, I created a file structure as given below:

```
    Directory: C:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                               
----                -------------     ------ ----                               
-a---        2014-01-18     14:13          0 file1.txt                          
-a---        2014-01-18     14:19          2 file2.txt                          


    Directory: C:\temp\subfolder


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                               
----                -------------     ------ ----                               
-a---        2014-01-18     14:14          2 file1.txt                          
-a---        2014-01-18     14:14          1 file2.txt                          
-a---        2014-01-18     14:14          0 file3.txt
```

As we can see, to get the newest file for each filename we want file1.txt and file3.txt from the subfolder and file2.txt from the C:\temp root folder.

And then ran the following command:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" -Recurse -File

$newestFiles = $files | Group Name | Foreach { $_.Group | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -First 1 }
$newestFiles
```

Which gave the following output:

```
    Directory: C:\temp\subfolder


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                               
----                -------------     ------ ----                               
-a---        2014-01-18     14:14          2 file1.txt                          


    Directory: C:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                               
----                -------------     ------ ----                               
-a---        2014-01-18     14:19          2 file2.txt                          


    Directory: C:\temp\subfolder


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                               
----                -------------     ------ ----                               
-a---        2014-01-18     14:14          0 file3.txt
```

Which is the output we wanted. Each of the items in the `$newestFiles` is a FileInfo object so they have all the properties of the FileInfo object, such as FullName and CreationTime.

Comment: That gets me the filename and the last created date, but not the file iself. is there a way to do that?

Comment: Not entirely sure about what you mean with "the file itself". If you mean the text of the file read using UTF8 encoding, you could append something like the following to the end of the last line (without the << and >>, but including the comma): <<,@{ N="FileContents";E={ Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path $_.Name } }>>

Comment: When I say the file itself, I mean an object where I can do (for example) `.Path` or `.FullName` etc of that file (which has the maximum lastcreateddate)

Comment: I have updated my answer, but please do update the question to further clarify what you have and what you want, so that it will be clearer for future readers and search engines.

Answer (score 5):

Here's **a more general solution to this problem**. It is the equivalent of this SQL:

```
# SELECT filename, max(date) FROM ListOfFiles GROUP BY filename 

$ListOfFiles |
Sort-Object -Property filename | group filename |
%{[PSCustomObject]@{
     filename = $_.name;
     max_date = ($_.Group | Sort-Object date | select -Last 1 -Property date).date; 
}}
```

So we first sort and group the list by the primary property and then for each record of the results extract the extra fields we care about from the `.Group` property.